# AEM Author Error.log : No renderer for extension html, cannot render resource MergedResource

Tags: aem

I am using AEM 6.5 Servicepack2 and getting this error in `error.log`, when we open any pages with `editor.html` in `Author`.

```
17.06.2020 08:03:30.656 ERROR [172.18.8.207 [1592395410151] GET /editor.html/content/tempProject/en/home/resources/tech-info.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet `  
***`No renderer for extension html, cannot render resource MergedResource`***   
`[path=/mnt/overlay/wcm/core/content/editor/jcr:content/content/items/content/header/items/headerbar/items/pageinfopopover/items/list/items/ct_translation/granite:rendercondition, resources=[/apps/wcm/core/content/editor/jcr:content/content/items/content/header/items/headerbar/items/pageinfopopover/items/list/items/ct_translation/granite:rendercondition]]
17.06.2020 08:03:30.657 ERROR [172.18.8.207 [1592395410151] GET /editor.html/content/tempProject/en/home/resources/tech-info.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet No renderer for extension html, cannot render resource MergedResource [path=/mnt/overlay/wcm/core/content/editor/jcr:content/content/items/content/header/items/headerbar/items/pageinfopopover/items/list/items/ct_tmupdate/granite:rendercondition, resources=[/apps/wcm/core/content/editor/jcr:content/content/items/content/header/items/headerbar/items/pageinfopopover/items/list/items/ct_tmupdate/granite:rendercondition]]`

**In Publisher :**  
`error.log.2020-06-13:13.06.2020 07:55:53.941 ERROR [172.18.8.207 [1592049353434]
GET //content/tempProject/en/home/resources/tech-info.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet`  
 ***`No renderer for extension html, cannot render resource JcrNodeResource,`***  
`type=nt:unstructured, superType=null, path=/content/tempProject/en/home/resources/tech-info/jcr:content/par_content/heroimage_msm_moved_13
error.log.2020-06-13:13.06.2020 07:55:53.941 ERROR [172.18.8.207 [1592049353434] GET /content/tempProject/en/home/resources/tech-info.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet No renderer for extension html, cannot render resource JcrNodeResource, type=nt:unstructured, superType=null, path=/content/tempProject/en/home/resources/tech-info/jcr:content/par_content/richtexteditor_msm_moved_13
```

Comment: We have already tried https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/issues/817 , https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-6184  but nothing worked for us.

Any suggestions how can we fix this?

Comment: your page (tech-info) does not have a resourceType or the page component that it is pointing to is not available.

Comment: this issue is there for all pages in the instance even for weretail pages. all pages have resourceType  and components are available in system.

Comment: then there might be something more seriously wrong with system. are all bundles active in system console? are there any other exceptions in log file during startup.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a clean instance and the SP2 only? Without any custom code.

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem with AEM 6.5.1 on CIS-hardened RHEL 8. Normally, this can be resolved by a restart, so maybe this will solve it for you at least.

Answer (score 0):

You probably overlayed `/apps/wcm/core/content/editor/jcr:content/content/items/content/header/items/headerbar/items/pageinfopopover/items/list/items/ct_translation/granite:rendercondition`  which was moved or removed after installing service pack.

Then after sling resource merging mechanism, some properties including sling:resourceType are missing in the merged resource.

Please check your overlays in apps and sync to the changes done by SP in libs.